# Infinite Sum Proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, proof-explanation

Conjecture:
There is no sequence $a_i$ of reals such that $\sum a_i^x=x$ for all $x>0$

My try at the Proof:
Suppose there is an $x$ such that $a_1^x+a_2^x ... = x$
Therefore, $a_1^2+a_2^2 ... = 2$ and $a_1^4+a_2^4 ... = 4$
If we let $a_n^x\in[0,1]$ for $\forall n$, then $a_n^2 \ge a_n^4$ for $\forall n$.
$2 = a_1^2+a_2^2 ... \ge a_1^4+a_2^4 ... = 4  \Rightarrow 2 \ge 4$, a contradiction.

Is this proof complete?  I do not know if I am justified in restricting all the $a$ values to $[0,1]$, although it is still an infinite sum.

Comment: Because there's some $x\in\mathbb{R}$ doesn't mean that $x=2$ is a valid solution I think.

Comment: ...or $x=4$, let alone both of them simultaneously.

Comment: I am trying to prove this by contradiction, so I assume that 2 and 4 are solutions.  Are you saying I should be more general and pick two arbitrary solutions where one is greater than the other so my contradiction still holds?

Comment: You might not be able to get two solutions, especially if even one doesn’t exist...

Comment: Sorry, I left out a crucial piece in the conjecture.  This sequence would have to stand for ALL positive $x$ values.

Comment: Mason, so a rewording would be: there is no sequence $a_i$ of reals such that $\sum a_k^x=x$ for all $x>0.$ Does that rewording capture what your conjecture says?

Comment: Coffeemath, yes that is what I was trying to say.  I will edit that in.  Thanks

Comment: If $x\to 0^+$, the sum tends to infinity...

Comment: farruhota, not if $a\in[0,1]$ like I mentioned.  But if that is not the case, then yes it diverges.  So I should mention that in the proof explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The question says $\{a_k\}$ is a sequence of real numbers. But $a_k^{x}$ is not a well defined number if $a_k<0$ so let us assume that $a_k$'s are non-negative. In that case your argument is correct except for the phrase 'we let $a_k^{x} \in [0,1]$. From the fact that $a_1^{n}+a_2^{n}+...=n$ it follows that $a_k^{n} \leq n$ for all n and k. Hence $a_k \leq n^{\frac 1 n}$ and we can let $n \to \infty$ to get $a_k\leq 1$ for all k. Now your argument works.

Comment: Even if you use the convention $a^x=e^{x(\ln|a|+i\pi)}=|a|^x(\cos\pi x+i\sin\pi x)$ when $a\lt0$, you have $a_k^{2n}\le2n$, hence $|a_k|\le(2n)^{1\over2n}$ and the proof still works.